# Looking for a function conditionally to be applied to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking at how I can apply a function to a column in a pandas dataframe. But I only want to apply this function if a condition is met.

```
import pandas as pd

def example_function(a, b):
    return a + b

data = dict(
    A = [1, 2],
    B = [4, 5],
    C = ["A", "B"],
)

example_df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

So I want to apply `example_function` using the values from A and B only if I have a `"B"` in Column C.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your expected output? `df["A"].add(df["B"]).where(df["C"].eq("B"))`?

Comment: yes, indeed. The real function is more complex. 

I want to apply `example_function` to A iff there is "B" in Column C

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.loc` to conditionally select which rows the function applies to, as well as specify the output column name.

```
example_df.loc[example_df.C.eq('B'), 'Sum'] = example_function(example_df.A,example_df.B)
```

Output

```
   A  B  C  Sum
0  1  4  A  NaN
1  2  5  B  7.0
```

Comment: That didn't work, because `example_function` doesn't accept a pandas series `example_df.A` but only values/ints. 

My solution now was to iterate in a for loof over example_df.loc[i]. That doesn't sound very pythonic / pandas but worked at the end.